# Difference between direct GRAPH API and PHP SDK result in page feed comments

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get the feed of a certain page through Facebook's GRAPH API, using their PHP SDK.

I have found that by calling this in my browser:

`https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXX/feed`

I'm getting the fresh feed, and finding a particular post **I only see my test comments, which were created x minutes ago, but missing the older comments** this item has.

And it is the other way around if I am getting the same feed through the SDK: **I am only seeing the old comments**.

Of course on Facebook, both type of comments are there... I haven't found any clue to this problem on developers.facebook.com

**UPDATE:**

This is the SDK call

```
include_once 'facebook.php';
$fb = new Facebook( array(
    'appId'     => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'secret'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'cookie'    => true
    ) );

    $feed = $fb->api('/tenytar/feed');
```

This is the browser call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/tenytar/feed
```

**Results of test:**

From the results I am checking the link with ID: 132297713489108_184041244974744

- On facebook this link has 3 likes and 2 comments
- in SDK call, the count of comments: 1 (only the older comment is there)
- in browser call, the count of comments: 1 (only the newer, my comment is there)

Comment: I have also checked with or without using an acess_token and the results are totally the same.

Comment: @Gregely Havlicsek dear put your code

Comment: @Awais Qarni I have included my code, dear. But the problem is not with the code, it is fully functional. I suspect a problem with some undocumented feature of facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the privacy settings the same on all of the comments? My guess is that you have different permissions when executing the URL (because you are probably logged in to Facebook in that browser session) as compared to your code which is using the app credentials.

Comment: The answer seems to be close to the real reason. It seems that the SDK's curl session produces different results than a simple curl call. Also there is an ongoing (8 months +) bug in limiting results in GRAPH and FQL APIs.